# React App - Why m count down is showing a dot whent the hours are equals to zero? And my minute is not 00 when pass of 59

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem with the minutes is this.
[image]

And the problem with the hour dot is:
[image]

```
const [time, setTime] = useState(60 * 60)
const hour = time / 3600
let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
const seconds = time % 60;

const [hourLeft, hourRight] = String(hour).padStart(2, 0).split('')
const [minuteLeft, minuteRight] = String(minutes).padStart(2, 0).split('')
const [secondLeft, secondRight] = String(seconds).padStart(2, 0).split('')

useEffect(() => {
    if(time > 0){
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setTime(time - 1)
        }, 1000)
    }
}, [time])
```

Answer (score 3):

Breaking the number up into left and right portions like that is really a strange way to go about it. Your code contains lots of errors.

First, you have

```
hour = time / 3600
```

You are not rounding, so therefore `hour` is going to always be a decimal between 0 and 1. So if you have 0.972222, you're then breaking up the digits of that number as if they were strings, so the first two will be `0` and `.` respectively.

What you need to be doing is getting the `floor` of this number. Then all of the other calculations after that are also incorrect. This is how you should be doing it:

```js
const hour = Math.floor(time / 3600);
const minutes = Math.floor(time % 3600 / 60);
const seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
```

Then forget about your crazy breaking numbers apart like strings and just pad them with zeroes. You can actually do it all in one step:

```js
const hour = String(Math.floor(time / 3600)).padStart(2, 0);
const minutes = String(Math.floor(time % 3600 / 60)).padStart(2, 0);
const seconds = String(Math.floor(time % 60)).padStart(2, 0);
```

Then just display those values:

```
return (
  <>
    {hour}:{minutes}:{seconds}
  </>
);
```

Or if you want to break them up into individual characters to display the background color like you have it, you could just do:

```
const timeStr = hour + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

return (
  <>
  {timeStr.split('').map((char, index) => {
    return <span key={index}>{char}</span>
  })}
  </>
);
```